# What protocols apart from TCP support cumulative acknowledgements?

Tags: tcp, osi

I know about cumulative and selective acknowledgements TCP protocol offers.

Do you know any other protocols (apart from TCP), that support cumulative acknowledgements?

Comment: There may be several that are proprietary and never see the light of day.  Why do you ask?

Comment: I'm preparing myself for an exam and I stumbled upon this question. All books and other resources mention TCP as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Trivial File Transfer Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350) (**TFTP**) running over UDP/69 also includes a built-in Acknowledgement system which is cumulative over the course of a file transfer.

Adding one:

IPsec includes a Sequence Number in the ESP/AH header. That can also be considered a cumulative acknowledgement. Although not in the strict sense that TCP or TFTP use it.

Answer (score 2):

One such protocol is OSPF, which uses a [Database Description Sequence Number](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_OSPFMessageFormats-3.htm) to keep track of database updates.

I'm sure there are others.